# calculation in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sum, wamp

I want to do a calculation on percentage of student attendance of each students, and it will display each attendance percentage that belongs to each of the students. Below is my code:

```
<tbody>
    <?php
        $data = "SELECT SUM(studAtt_endTime - studAtt_startTime) FROM studentAttendance";   
        $result = $conn->query($data)
        or die ("Error: ".mysqli_error($conn)); //look if theres any error
            while($ser2=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    ?>

    <?php
        $counter = 1;
        $data = "SELECT * FROM student INNER JOIN studentAttendance ON student.stud_matric=studentAttendance.student_stud_matric
                            INNER JOIN course ON course.course_code=studentAttendance.course_course_code
                            WHERE course_course_code LIKE '%$_GET[course]%'
                            GROUP BY student_stud_matric";
                $result = $conn->query($data)
                or die ("Error: ".mysqli_error($conn)); //look if theres any error      
                    while($ser=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    ?>
                <tr>
                <td><center><?php echo $counter; 
                            $counter++; ?></center></td>
                <td><?php echo $ser["stud_matric"];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $ser["stud_name"];?></td>
                <td><?php
                        $a = $ser["course_contacthour"];
                        $b = "14";
                        $tch = ($a * 2 ) * $b; // tch= total contact hour in 14 week
                        echo number_format($ser2["SUM(studAtt_endTime - studAtt_startTime)"] / $tch * 100, 2);?></td>
                </tr>
                                    <?php
                                    }
                                    ?>
                                    <?php
                                    }
                                    ?>
                                </tbody>
```

The problem is, this code will sum up all the students attendance percentage and it will show the same percentage for every students, instead of percentage on the student itself.

Comment: You have a nested sl query that uses `$result` - which is used also by the outer query which will probably cause issues.

Comment: There are other issues too. Why two queries? YOu missed quotes around the parameter name in the 2nd query ( ie: `'%$_GET[course]%'` should be `'%{$_GET['course']}%'`, and what is `number_format($ser2["SUM(studAtt_endTime - studAtt_startTime)"] / $tch * 100, 2)`??

Comment: I have two queries because it cannot be done by only one query, or its me cannot write the right query.
`number_format($ser2["SUM(studAtt_endTime - studAtt_startTime)"] / $tch * 100, 2)` is the calculation for the student attendance percentage.
Hence, i need the `SUM(studAtt_endTime - studAtt_startTime)` from the first query. But, the result displayed are calculated from the total 'SUM(studAtt_endTime - studAtt_startTime)' of all students, not for each that particular students like I want. @RamRaider

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <?php

                $counter = 1;

                /* Some rudimentary filtering at the very least, better use prepared statements or PDO */
                $course = addslashes( filter_input( INPUT_GET,'course',FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING ) );

                /* I think you can combine the two sql queries and have only 1 loop */
                $data = "select *,
                            ( select sum( `studatt_endtime` - `studatt_starttime` ) from `studentattendance` ) as 'sum'
                            from `student` s
                            inner join `studentattendance` a on s.`stud_matric`=a.`student_stud_matric`
                            inner join `course` c on c.`course_code`=a.`course_course_code`
                            where a.`course_course_code` like '%".$course."%'
                            group by a.`student_stud_matric`;";

                /* Query the db - do not reveal too much information if there is a problem */   
                $result = $conn->query( $data ) or die ("Error: Something went wrong...");
                if( $result ){

                    /* Loop through recordset */
                    while( $ser=$result->fetch_object() ) {

                        /* Do your calculations */
                        $a = $ser->course_contacthour;
                        $b = "14";
                        $tch = ( $a * 2 ) * $b;
                        $tot=number_format( $ser->sum / $tch * 100, 2);

                        /* write the output */
                        echo '
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <center>'.$counter.'</center>
                            </td>
                            <td>'.$ser->stud_matric.'</td>
                            <td>'.$ser->stud_name.'</td>
                            <td>'.$tot.'</td>
                        </tr>';

                        $counter++;
                    }
                }
                @mysqli_free_result( $result );
            ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, this code i more make sense tq so much! But still i cannot get the calculation right. See what i get on my edited post above @RamRaider

Answer (score 0):

Rather than edit the above / below and confuse things, I'll post some other stuff here. Without seeing the schema I am not sure if the following SQL is correct in that I do not know if the columns `studatt_endtime` and `studatt_starttime` are in the `studentAttendance` table or the `student` table so you might need to change the prefix used:

```
/* Now the `sum` is pertinent to the student whereas before it was not */
$data = "select *,
        sum( a.`studatt_endtime` - a.`studatt_starttime` ) as 'sum'
        from `student` s
        inner join `studentattendance` a on s.`stud_matric`=a.`student_stud_matric`
        inner join `course` c on c.`course_code`=a.`course_course_code`
        where a.`course_course_code` like '%".$course."%'
        group by a.`student_stud_matric`;";
```

Also, I do not know what you are trying to calculate really and maths was never a strong point for me but the calculation seems a little ambiguous in that there is no adherance to the `BODMAS` method of calculation, where `BODMAS` stands for `Brackets, Order, Division, Multiplication, Addition, Subtraction` - [see here for details](https://www.mathsisfun.com/operation-order-bodmas.html) so the calculation could be interprested in different ways like:

```
$tot=number_format( $ser->sum / ( $tch * 100 ), 2 );
$alt_tot=number_format( ( $ser->sum / $tch ) * 100, 2 );
```